# redirecting with if statment based on cookie using header('location:') gives weird error in firefox

Tags: php, firefox, redirect, header

I am trying to redirect my visitors to for example `http://localhost/site/test.php?lang=en_US`based on the country code in the cookie like this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['country'])) 
{
        $country = $_COOKIE['country'];
        header('Location: test.php?lang=en_US');  

        if ($country == "NO"){              
        header('Location: test.php?lang=no_NO');    
        }                       
}
else
{
    header('Location: test.php?lang=en_US');  
}
```

But i get this weird error in firefox: `The page isn't redirecting properly`

Found a solution:

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang']))
{

        if (isset($_COOKIE['country'])) 
        {
                $country = $_COOKIE['country'];
                $redirect = "en_US";

                if ($country == "NO"){              
                $redirect = "no_NO";    
                header('Location: crime.php?lang='.$redirect); 
                }   

                if ($country == "EN"){              
                $redirect = "en_US";    
                header('Location: crime.php?lang='.$redirect); 
                }   

        }
        else
        {
            header('Location: crime.php?lang=en_US'); 
        }


}
```

Comment: You should call exit() after the redirect. Though that isn't the cause of the infinite loop.

Comment: Notice how this is a condition which doesn't lead to a redirect.  However, keep in mind that any value in `lang` will avoid the redirect, even an invalid language setting. Also, I suggest that you accept goffrie's answer, as it is correct and was useful in finding a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it is unconditionally redirecting, and always to itself, causing an infinite loop which Firefox detects and stops. You need to add conditions to prevent redirects once the final page has been reached.

Comment: Sounds logic. How do I stop it from redirecting once the correct page has loaded ? What cause the infinite loop? Is it the if (isset($_COOKIE['country']))?

Comment: @ganjan It's the very nature of that code.  No matter what, you're redirecting.  There is no condition that doesn't redirect.  Step through the code, and you'll see it.  If the cookie is set it redirects, if it isn't set it also redirects.